# EDI.Net Lists limited to 50

Tags: c#, arrays, parsing, edi, edi.net

I am trying to deserialise large EDI messages using indice-co/EDI.Net but the messages that I am deserialising are in lists which are limitted to 50. I'm wondering if anyone has come accross this issue before and whether they have managed to fix it.

I don't know whether adding a code sample would help but whether using an array or a list it is still limited.

Thanks in advance

Comment: the EDI standards themselves often limit lists to certain numbers of items. Not all libraries and tools respect those limits, so you may come across an EDI message that contains more items in a list than it should. I'd first check whether the segment in question has such a limit and whether your messages exceed it.

Comment: Is there a schema that contgains the limit?

Comment: I don't have any limits set on any of the segments. There are no limits in the specification sheet for it either. I'm assuming that its somewhere in the source code for the package that I cant find.

Comment: @Dominic.New.Work Can you provide a gist so we can see the models and the sample edi transmission. Or update your question to include them